# Text not displaying with equal distance tkinter label

Tags: python, tkinter, format, label, string-formatting

when the go button is pressed 10 tkinter labels display two strings, and all 10 labels must have equal distance between the two strings.

For some reason the spaces are just not equal, but what is weird is that, if I print the strings in the console they all have equal space

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter
from random import randint

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry('700x700')
def go():
        for label in container:
            stringa = ('A' * randint(5, 10))
            stringb = ('B' * randint(10, 15))
            label.configure(text=((stringa.ljust(30) + stringb)))


global container
container = []

for count in range(10):
    tkinterlabel = Label(root, text='hi',anchor=NW)
    tkinterlabel.pack(anchor='nw')
    container.append(tkinterlabel)

Button(root, text='go', command=lambda: go()).pack()
```

Here's what the output is, in the tkinter window and console window

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible solutions to this problem.

1. Use a fixed font, such as "Courier New" or "Lucida Console" to display your labels. Then, the blanks will have the same width as the letters and your columns align just like in the console.
2. (recommended) Use two columns of labels to display your data.

The second approach yould be implemented by adding two Labels in a tuple for each label and changing your functions to:

```
def go():
        for label in container:
            stringa = ('A' * randint(5, 10))
            stringb = ('B' * randint(10, 15))
            label[0].configure(text=stringa)
            label[1].configure(text=stringb)

for count in range(10):
    l1 = Label(root, text='hi')
    l1.grid(row=count,column=0,sticky=W)
    l2 = Label(root, text='hi')
    l2.grid(row=count,column=1,padx = 20,sticky=W)
    
    container.append((l1,l2))

Button(root, text='go', command=lambda: go()).grid(row=12,column=0,sticky=W)
```

EDIT: I changed the layout to `.grid` to align the labels correctly on one line. Therefore, you would also need to put the button in this layout.

Comment: fix the Indentation?

Comment: thankyouuuu  I was able to manipulate the second approach to fit my code and it worked! thanks